# Remove duplicate values from JSON with jq

Tags: json, unix, unique, jq

i'm merging two json-files with jq

```
(group_by( [."contraction", "definitions"]) | map((.[0]|del(."definitions" [])) + { "definitions": (map(."definitions" [])) }))
```

which leads to the following result:

```
  [
  {
    "contraction": "TEST_1",
    "definitions": [
      {
        "search": "1",
        "replace": "12"
      },
      {
        "search": "3",
        "replace": "4"
      },
      {
        "search": "6",
        "replace": "2"
      },
      {
        "search": "1",
        "replace": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "contraction": "TEST_2",
    "definitions": [
      {
        "search": "A",
        "replace": "post"
      },
      {
        "search": "B",
        "replace": "prae"
      },
      {
        "search": "A",
        "replace": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but now i want to get rid of the duplicate entries which have the same string in their search-attribute.

I've tried unique and unique_by filters, but it leads to complie errors.

the result , should be:

```
  [
  {
    "contraction": "TEST_1",
    "definitions": [
      {
        "search": "1",
        "replace": "12"
      },
      {
        "search": "3",
        "replace": "4"
      },
      {
        "search": "6",
        "replace": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "contraction": "TEST_2",
    "definitions": [
      {
        "search": "A",
        "replace": "post"
      },
      {
        "search": "B",
        "replace": "prae"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

is this possible with jq? because i'm not trying to filter keys but normal values. any ideas?

The code on [JQPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/xIax5gZAnT)

Comment: You'll want to use [`unique_by(path_expr)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#unique,unique_by(path_exp))

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: @peak thanks for your reply. i've edit my posting and now it shows what i'm expecting.

Comment: @Aaron how do you mean it? Like  a filter?

Comment: Yes, the steps producing the description arrays should be piped into unique_by. If you add your input(s) to your post I'll be able to test it and post an answer.

Comment: @Aaron you can find them here : https://jqplay.org/s/xIax5gZAnT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply extend your filter with this:

```
map( .definitions |= unique_by(.search) )
```